# what's the kernel version when ip_conntrack become nf_conntrack_ipv4

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

In my project i have to modprobe a module ,I googled and know when the kernel version less than xx.xx.xx the moudle is  ip_conntrack,but the article does not say the version is.Then ask man for help,got nothing,would anyone please tell me where to find the version.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <linux/version.h>
int main()
{
    #if LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(xx,xx,xx)
        system("modprobe nf_conntrack_ipv4");
    #else
        system("modprobe ip_conntrack");
    #endif
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Reading comments for [`smtp-gated.conf`](https://manned.org/smtp-gated.conf.5) it looks like as early as 2.6.32. But the comments also read like the module was backported and may be available stand-alone with earlier kernels.

Comment: @jww I just install centos5.11 the kernel 2.6.18, cat /proc/modules | grep ip_conntrack is existed,now I am download centos6.0,I have no ways to find it out.

Comment: Maybe you can try `ret = system("modprobe nf_conntrack_ipv4");` first. If it fails then call `ret = system("modprobe ip_conntrack");`. I'm not sure what to do if both fail...